# GitHub API request to sample realtime commit / push activity

Tags: javascript, git, api, github

I'm wondering if GitHub offers an API that allows developers to sample `git commit` or `git push` activities in realtime (activity from users across the globe) similar to what Twitter offers?

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/sample-realtime/guides/recovery-and-redundancy

Comment: Have you looked at the GitHub documentation for its API to see if there are any endpoints that satisfy your requirements?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes such as this `https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events` but it seems like the api response doesn't contain location data

Comment: If you refrain from putting backticks around a URL this site will format it as a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GitHub event page](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/) inculdes many events, that can then be monitored through [Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

> but it seems like the api response doesn't contain location data

However, none of those events would include directly the location: you might it with a secondary query for [the user/author of the commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user), but don't forget that field is set (or not) by the user and is not accurate.